# API design: Giving the signin endpoint a noun name

Tags: api-design

[Nouns are good and verbs are bad](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_nouns_are_good_verbs_are_bad/).

HTTP codes + the endpoint `/user/123` can signify user create, read, update and delete operations. But what should the `signin` and `signout` endpoint be called?

How can i avoid method-driven-naming my API?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: Random strangers posting provocative blog titles are bad. Having an understanding of the fundamentals to call out that author is good.  Don't take "rules of thumb" as universal truths.

Comment: @GlenH7 you mean, we're invited to **[Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)** ...yet again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your signin process works, the noun the client is requesting when they sign in might be something like a `ticket` or a `session`.